# Display vertical-scrollbar for Jquery Mobile for ipad2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to create dialog with div area that can scroll in it. Currently I'm not found the best way to do it. Welcome every suggestion :).

Comment: What ways have you found so far? And what makes you think that what you found is not the best way? What is it in particular that you don't like about what you found or developed yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, iOS does not support that method of scrolling until iOS 5 which is due out in month or so. See this link: http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2011/06/ios-5-brings-native-app-style-scrolling-to-web-apps.php

If you can't wait and want to do it today, check out Joe Hewitt's Scrollability: https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability